# Add/change the DataServiceQuery<T> in Silverlight

Tags: linq, wcf-data-services, silverlight-5.0, caliburn.micro

I am developing a Silverlight 5 application with Caliburn.Micro(for those not familiar with Caliburn don't worry, you need not understand Caliburn stuff in order to answer my question) as a MVVM framework, in which I need to read some data from SQL tables. I have opted for a WCF Data Service(reason is beside the point).

In order to make things general and reusable I have created a view model which takes a `DataServiceQuery<TEntity>` and the `URI` of the service and loads the data. I have also created a view for this view model, with a telerik RadGridView in order to show the data and an Caliburn IResult to show the view model in a child window. I want to use this view model and view whenever I need to select something from a table since in my application I have many forms with fields on which the user needs to select something from a large list(SQL table).

```
public class SelectDBEntitiesViewModel<TEntity, TContext> : DialogScreenBase, IAmClean
        where TEntity : class, new()
        where TContext : DataServiceContext
    {
        public SelectDBEntitiesViewModel()
        {
        }

        public void Load()
        {
            // load
        }

        public DataServiceQuery<TEntity> Query{ get; set; }

        public void Filter()
        {

            Query = _originalQuery.AddQueryOption("$filter", "startswith(" + _filterProperty + ",'" + FilterValue + "')");
            Load();
        }
    }
```

So from some other view model in a coroutine I create this IResult class like this:

```
public IEnumerable<IResult> SelectInternalBeneficiary()
    {
        SelectDBEntitiesResult<InternalBeneficiary, QMSEntities> r = new SelectDBEntitiesResult<InternalBeneficiary, QMSEntities>(_oDataUri);
        r.Query = (from ib in r.DataContext.InternalBeneficiaries where (ib.Firma == Model.GroupCompany) select ib) as DataServiceQuery<InternalBeneficiary>;            r.PageSize = 2;
        r.ColumnSettingsName = UserSettings.SEL_INTERNALBENEFICIARIES_GRID;
        r.Header = "SELECT AN INTERNAL BENEFICIARY";
        r.Subtitle = "List of all departments";
        yield return r;
        Model.InternalBeneficiary = r.SelectedObject.DenumireDepartament;
    }
```

So when this method runs there is a child window opening, the view model loads data and the grid in the view is loaded.

Everything works ok for now but in the view I have a textbox in the upper right corner which I want to use to filter the data by adding some new clause to the query. This I need to do inside my general `SelectDBEntitiesViewModel` but the problem is that the query that this view model is using is received from outside as a parameter. I have tried the following in the Filter method:

```
Query = _originalQuery.AddQueryOption("$filter", "startswith(" + _filterProperty + ",'" + FilterValue + "')");
```

but when I run the application I get of course this error:

```
Can't add query option '$filter' because it would conflict with the query options from the translated Linq expression.
```

I understand what is going on(I already have a where clause in the query and can't add another filter) but I don't know how to work around it.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I managed to find out how you can create `Expressions` and add them to a `Query`:

This method adds a starts with type of filtering to an `IQueryable<T>`

```
private IQueryable<T> StartsWithQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> query, string propertyValue, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
        {
            ParameterExpression e = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
            MemberExpression m = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.MakeMemberAccess(e, propertyInfo);
            ConstantExpression c = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));
            MethodInfo mi = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
            System.Linq.Expressions.Expression call = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(m, mi, c);
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, e);
            return query.Where(lambda);
    }
```

This method adds an equals to type of filtering to an `IQueryable<T>`:

```
private IQueryable<T> EqualsQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> query, string propertyValue, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
        {
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> additionalExpression =
               System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Equal(
                       System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.MakeMemberAccess(
                           System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "te"),
                           typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(_filterProperty)),

               System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(FilterValue)),
                   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "te"));

            return query.Where(additionalExpression);
        }
```

Expression trees are pretty powerful